# Jupyter does not create a new notebook under the current directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I updated my Jupyter Notebook and it does not create a new notebook under the current directory as it used to. Instead, it always creates a new notebook under the start-up directory.This happens on my Mac and Windows computers. How can I fix this?

1) Creating a new notebook under `project1`

[image]

2) A new notebook was successfully created

[image]

3) However, this notebook was created under the jupyter start-up directory rather than `project1`

[image]

Jupyter did not behave like this before. Is this a bug or intended behavior?

Here are my Jupyter related package versions.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyter                   1.0.0            py36h598a6cc_0
jupyter_client            5.2.2                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36hccf5b1c_1
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                    py36_1    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.3.3                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h79cf704_0
jupyter_highlight_selected_word 0.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.0                    py36_1    conda-forge
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.4.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                0.27.0           py36hd3092eb_2
jupyterlab_launcher       0.4.0            py36h93e02e9_0
notebook                  5.3.1                    py36_1
```

Comment: You may get some help from this config file paramters http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Comment: [md-johirul-islam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3416272/md-johirul-islam), so this is an intended update? Also would you please point out which line in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` I need to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [ilyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4241251/ilyas)'s advice, updated my `notebook` to [5.4.0](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/releases/tag/5.4.0) and [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3263) was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Run
`conda update conda`

And then:

`conda update --all`

in your anaconda prompt. There are recent updates to jupyter that will fix this issue.

Comment: Would you please tell me the name of the package and the version number that fixes this? There are some packages I cannot update.